# Changing Unix group for files

Tags: permissions, group

I have a file that a colleague and I are editing together, on a Unix system.  We are using Unix group permissions to edit it.  We have one Unix group that we are both members of. Whenever I save the file, it changes the Unix group to one that he is not a member of.  Is there any way to stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your options are to set the setgid bit (`chmod g+s`) on the directory to make files created within it match its group ID, or to use the `newgrp` command to open a shell with the desired group ID before editing the file.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. I think what the what he needs is  the `setgid` bit, not to the sticky bit. From Wikipedia: `Setting the setgid permission on a directory (chmod g+s) causes new files and subdirectories created within it to inherit its group ID, rather than the primary group ID of the user who created the file`. Activating the sticky bit on the directory will only make sure that only the directories' files' owner, the directory's owner or root can modify the directories' files.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to switch group using the command `newgrp`. It may ask for the group password that you may set with `gpasswd`.

Answer (score 2):

Uno. change your default login group number to be the same between the two people

```
username:x:500:514::/home/username:/bin/tcsh
# Where 514 is the group id.
```

Duo: create a new user id , with a password only known by the two people involved. `chown` the file to be owned by the new userid.   Before editing the file in question, `su`to the new userid.

Trio:.

```
cp $EDITOR to $HOME; \# in this example pico
chmod g+s $HOME/pico;
chgrp RELEVANTGROUP $HOME/pico;
```

Quattro:

```
sudo chgrp RELEVANTGROUP some/path/to/file \# may require root
```

Cinco:  Create a few Google account and edit the thing SIMULTANEOUSLY in Google
docs. (it is neat to watch where the other person is typing). Make a point of 
changing the sharing perms in Google Docs for "anyone with the link"

Hexo:  Split the file in two and have each editor only work on half.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `umask` on your system.

Comment: OK, default dot files set by our sys admins use a umask of 022.  What's a good umask for "don't change it!"?

Comment: umask is for default permissions, not group ID.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good article about Sticky-Bit and other advanced permission settings:
https://notes-from-a-dev.blogspot.com/2011/03/modes-and-permission-sticky-bit.html